# php: file_get_contents(url) failed to open stream when calling a page that has a json response

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have the following code:

```
<?php
//first try
$url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com';
echo '<pre>';
print_r(file_get_contents($url));
echo '</pre>';


//second try
$url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=the dark night';
echo '<pre>';
print_r(file_get_contents($url));
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The first try works fine. However, the second try give the following error message with no more details:
`$file_get_contents(http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=the dark night): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!`

Note that,pc has windows 8.1 x64, I've tried both wamp server and xampp. I did make sure that both of `$php.ini` files have enabled both of the extentions `$extension=php_openssl.dll` and `$extension=php_curl.dll`

Comment: Try replacing spaces with `%20` in your url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to encode your url using `urlencode`:

```
$url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t='.urlencode('the dark night');
echo '<pre>';
print_r(file_get_contents($url));
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of [file_get_contents](http://docs.php.net/file_get_contents) say

> **Note:** If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you
>   need to encode the URI with [urlencode()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

So replace

```
$url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=the dark night';
```

with

```
$url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t='.urlencode('the dark night');
```